# score corruption with shadow variables

Tags: optaplanner

In my Optaplanner Model i have a WorkOrder (PlanningEntity) that i plan on different locations(PlanningVariable).

Several WorkOrders are connected. 
It is not a pure chain. Several WorkOrders can connect to one and one can connect to several following.

The orders have a start and stop variable and I use it in the rules to prevent more than one order in one place at a time and so on. 
They also have a duration (internal variable - not used in score rules) and for some WorkOrders (mainly pure transports) the duration changes due to the former WorkOrders location and the following WorkOrders location

Now I made start and stop CustomShadowVariable referencing the location PlanningVariable with a Listener class. In that listener I recalculate all durations due to the different locations and set the start and stop values accordingly.

```
   @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = 
         StartTimeUpdatingVariableListener.class,
          sources = { @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "workLocation")})
   public Date getStart() {
    return start;
   }
```

and

```
@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerRef = 
  @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "start"))
public Date getStop() {
 return stop;
}
```

The solved scenarios seems to be fine BUT in the Assert Modes (full and fast) I get score corruptions due to the shadowvariables:

```
VariableListener corruption: the entity (WorkOrder{…})'s shadow variable (WorkOrder.start)'s corrupted value (Fri Mar 23 20:02:41 CET 2018) changed to uncorrupted value (Fri Mar 23 20:02:36 CET 2018) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.
Maybe the VariableListener class (StartTimeUpdatingVariableListener) for that shadow variable (WorkOrder.start) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed after completedAction (Initial score calculated).
```

The variable start is only changed at one place and there the scoreDirector is informed about that change:

```
  scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(order, "start");
  order.setStart(newStart);
  scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(order, "start");
```

I am at the end of any ideas how to proceed.